# Spark CSV Reader quoted numerics

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently reading in CSV data using the following code:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = getSparkSession().read()
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("quote", '"')
            .option("sep", ',')
            .schema(schema)
            .csv(path)
            .toDF();
```

Which is directed to a CSV file that has rows that look like this:

```
"abc","city","123"
```

as well as another file that has rows that look like this:

```
"abc","city",123
```

The second one works fine because the schema I pass is

```
string, string, long
```

the first one results in `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "123"`

Is it possible for the CSV reader to properly read CSVs in both valid formats? Assuming options are passed.

I am using Spark 2.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code actually crashes for me. I suspect that **using characters instead of Strings is the culprit**. Using `'"'.toString` for `.option("quote",...)` fixes the crash, and works. Furthermore, you may want to also define the escape character, as in the following code.

In Cloudera's Spark2, I was able to use the following to parse both quoted and unquoted numbers to `DecimalType`, with a pre-defined schema:

```
spark.read
            .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
            .option("escape", "\"")
            .option("delimiter", DELIMITER)
            .option("header", HASHEADER.toString)
            .option("quote", "\"")
            .option("nullValue", null)
            .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", value = true)
            .schema(SCHEMA)
            .csv(PATH)
```

Examples of parsed numbers (from unit tests):

```
1.0
11
"15.23"
""
 //empty field
"0.0000000001"
1111111111111.
 000000000. //with leading space
```

This also works in my tests for `IntegerType` - it can be parsed regardless of quotes.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is my mistake. I am not using characters in my actual code. I am retrieving the parameters from my schema creation class which is returning them as strings not characters (for simplicity I accidently used `'"'` instead of `"\""`. My apologies. I am still receiving NFE with your code. Possibly a difference in Cloudera's Spark2 version and Java's 2.1.1 maven build.

Comment: @DeeVu No, that's not it - I just modified my build.sbt to use 2.1.1 and my unit test is still green. How did you define your schema?

Comment: Good catch. You were right this was a schema problem all along. My demoset was trying to cast ONE of my 100s of columns to an integer when it was a decimal. I can safely say I am banging my head against my desk.

Answer (score 1):

Use `inferSchema` property which automatically identifies the data type of the  columns.

```
var data= sparkSession.read
      .option("header", hasColumnHeader)
      .option("inferSchema", "true").csv(inputPath);
```

Comment: I cannot use inferSchema. It does not work properly for all my client datasets. We have our own infer schema function which works exponentially better. We detect that "123" and 123 are both numeric, but how can we tell the spark dataset to ignore the quotes to avoid the NFE.

Comment: why cant you change the data type of the column once after read that column as string.?
You may use withColumnRenamed and withColumn api as work around for this.

Comment: I've tried that. You cannot change the datatype of a string column to a numeric column as it results in `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of bigint`

Comment: I figured it out with that comment. Thanks. Totally spaced.

`Column newColumn = dataset.col(columnName).cast(DataTypes.LongType);`

`dataset.withColumn(columnName, newColumn);`